# Form names structure

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

Hy, 
I have an form with many imbricated elements that need to keep relation on save. 
 ex: I have an form with multiple banks, and each bank may have multiple employers. 
How will be right structure for keeping relation of each employers to corespondent bank.

```
    <form>
input name="bank_name[]"
input name="bank_email[]"
input name="employer_name[]"
input name="employer_name[]"
input name="employer_name[]"

input name="bank_name[]"
input name="bank_email[]"
input name="employer_name[]"
</form>
```

Any ideas? form are saving with php, if matter. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<input name="bank[0][name]" />
<input name="bank[0][email]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer_name][]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer_name][]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer_name][]" />

<input name="bank[1][name]" />
<input name="bank[1][email]" />
<input name="bank[1][employer_name][]" />
<input name="bank[1][employer_name][]" />
<input name="bank[1][employer_name][]" />

...
```

You can do this in a loop to loop as many banks as you like. This is common in payment gateways that they use the indexes to create multi-dimensional arrays.

**EDIT:**

If let's say employer has multiple attributes, you should use the similar fashion to achieve the multi-dimensional arrays:

```
<input name="bank[0][name]" />
<input name="bank[0][email]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][0][name]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][0][email]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][0][address]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][1][name]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][1][email]" />
<input name="bank[0][employer][1][address]" />

....
```

Comment: i know  this, but i add new html row for employer, or for bank with employeer with ajax, and array count is unknown, or need to reformat it with js, so It is a solution that I did not want to use..because of this I wrote in forum

Comment: Hmm I don't quite get your comment. Basically the idea of this is to achieve what you are asking - keeping the parent-child relationship in the submission. What's your other concern?

Comment: @mpc, based on your input, this is the proper approach with multi-dimensional arrays. if your case is different, better update your question with real data structure.